# Find value in column after a certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with some values.

```
user   action
user1  login
user1  left
user1  right
user1  right
user2  login
user2  right
user1  login
user1  right
user2  login
user2  left
user2  right
user2  right
user2  login
user2  right
```

based on the action "login", i need to find the next action "right"
so the output would be

```
user   action
user1  right
user2  right
user1  right
user2  right
user2  right
```

I don't need just to search for "right".
I want to make sure that "login" was triggered, like in a flow.

I tried to search "login" with shift, but I could only grab "right" if it was on the second / third row etc.
I would need to get the next action no matter how many actions below it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set 2 boolean masks:

1. `m1` to signal within a group `'login'` has been appeared before.
2. `m2` to match for the rows where `action` equals `'right'`

and filter the rows when both conditions met and get first entry within the group by `GroupBy.first()`:

```
group = (df['user'].ne(df['user'].shift()) | df['action'].eq('login')).cumsum()

m1 = df['action'].eq('login').groupby(group).cumsum() > 0
m2 = df['action'].eq('right')

df[m1 & m2].groupby(group, as_index=False).first()
```

**Input:**

```
     user action
0   user1  login
1   user1   left
2   user1  right
3   user1  right
4   user2  login
5   user2  right
6   user1  login
7   user1  right
8   user2  login
9   user2   left
10  user2  right
11  user2  right
12  user2  login
13  user2  right
14  user3   left
15  user3  right
```

**Output**

```
    user action
0  user1  right
1  user2  right
2  user1  right
3  user2  right
4  user2  right
```

Comment: But if the user has more "right" actions after "login", it would still capture all, and I only need the first one.
I have updated the question.

Comment: @Calafalas  See my edit above and try again.

Comment: It's not good, because it searches for the first every occurrence of each user, and I need to see every action from the flow no matter how many "login" the user does

Comment: @Calafalas   Ok, the requirement is much clearer now with your better sample data.  Let me fine-tune it then.

Comment: @Calafalas  Pleased to help!  Happy programming!  :-)